# How to Display Current date+current time + 1 hour in text box in php

Tags: php, laravel

I need to display current date plus current time +1 hour in PHP laravel textbox
my code as follows

```
    <input  name="SuggestedDate" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" placeholder="SuggestedDate" type="datetime-local" id="payment_due_at" value="">
```

Comment: Something like `value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1)->toDateTimeString(); }}"`

Comment: @sta  am new to laravel and PHP can you help me to write the code

Comment: just replace your `value=""` with the following code

Comment: @sta am getting this error syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'

Comment: Opps, try again with `value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1)->toDateTimeString() }}"`

Comment: @sta noting is coming

Comment: @sta i put like dis  <input  name="SuggestedDate" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" placeholder="SuggestedDate" type="datetime-local" id="payment_due_at" value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1)->toDateTimeString() }}">

Comment: `<input name="SuggestedDate" class="form-control" id="inputSubject" placeholder="SuggestedDate" type="text" id="payment_due_at" value="{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(1)->toDateTimeString() }}">`

Comment: @sat now its working but the problem is if change the type my picker is not working

Comment: I dont know which date time picker you are using, but may be your date time picker accept date as [tag:javascript] instead of input value. Post another question with your input field and the js code together

Comment: @sat actually i need if one customer enters a form there is one date field .in the date field by default need to show current date+plustime+extra one hr. and the customer can also change the date and time using the picker